# Search multiline set of record from file using perl

Tags: perl

I have a file having set of records in multi lines. I need to read that log file for set of records and write each separate record into separate file. File same as below ..

```
VMEMBER NAME  CMPJFCB                                                            
V//NGJFCB   JOB (P,KBTB,BB2994),'MVSNBY-CMP',CLASS=A,                    JOB40337
V//           REGION=0M,MSGCLASS=W,NOTIFY=&SYSUID    
v// CYX sss eee
VMEMBER NAME  CMPJFCB                                                            
V//NGJFCB   JOB (P,KBTB,BB2994),'MVSNBY-CMP',CLASS=A,                    JOB40337
V//           REGION=0M,MSGCLASS=W,NOTIFY=&SYSUID    
v
v//
VMEMBER NAME  CMPJFCB                                                            
V//NGJFCB   JOB (P,KBTB,BB2994),'MVSNBY-CMP',CLASS=A,                    JOB40337
V//           REGION=0M,MSGCLASS=W,NOTIFY=&SYSUID    
v
v//
v/*
and so on ...
```

so from above start point we know "VMEMBER NAME" but end point we dont know. it can be ended with "V" or "V//" or anything.
I tried with range match  as below

```
$line =~ m{VMEMBER .. v\/\*}
```

but problem is the last pattern (v*) because we are not sure what would be last line of record. Please help.

output for first set should be

```
VMEMBER NAME  CMPJFCB                                                            
V//NGJFCB   JOB (P,KBTB,BB2994),'MVSNBY-CMP',CLASS=A,                    JOB40337
V//           REGION=0M,MSGCLASS=W,NOTIFY=&SYSUID    
v// CYX sss eee
```

second set would be

```
VMEMBER NAME  CMPJFCB                                                            
V//NGJFCB   JOB (P,KBTB,BB2994),'MVSNBY-CMP',CLASS=A,                    JOB40337
V//           REGION=0M,MSGCLASS=W,NOTIFY=&SYSUID    
v
v//
```

like this.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to set Perl's record separator (`$/`) to 'VMEMBER NAME', so it effectively chunks the file by that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = 'VMEMBER NAME';
my $recNum;

while (<>) {
    chomp;

    if (/\S/) {
        open my $fh, '>', "record\_" . ++$recNum . '.txt' or die $!;
        print $fh $/ . $_;
    }
}
```

Usage: `perl logFile`

This script creates a set of files, record_1.txt ... record_n.txt, which contains your desired output.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

This program will do as you ask. It expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line, and generates files `File_001.txt`, `File_002.txt` etc. up to the end of the file. You can modify the format that `sprintf` uses if you want to change the output file names.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $outfh;
my $n;

while (<>) {
  if (/^VMEMBER/) {
    my $file = sprintf "File_%03d.txt", ++$n;
    open $outfh, '>', $file;
  }
  print $outfh $_ if $outfh;
}

close $outfh if $outfh;
```

Comment: Elegant.  What does Perl do with the file handles in `$outfh`, since the handle's only explicitly closed at the end?  Is a file automatically closed when `$outfh` takes on a new value?

Comment: @Kenosis: Yes that's right. [`perldoc -f close`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) says *"You don't have to close FILEHANDLE if you are immediately going to do another open on it, because open closes it for you."* There's no real need to explicitly close it at the end either, but if the close is going to fail it's nicer if it doesn't happen during Perl tidy-up.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is one way to do it.**

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my %hash;
my $counter = 0;
my $group;

open my $fh, '<', 'data1.txt' # <-- The path to your file comes here!.
    or die "can't open data1.txt $1";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /^VMEMBER/) {
    $group = 'Group Number: ' . $counter++;
    }
    push @{ $hash{ $group } }, $line;
}

#By this point in the script all of your record have been separated in different set.
#As you can see in the output below.  

foreach my $group (sort keys %hash) {
    print "$group\n", @{ $hash{ $group } }, "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Group Number: 0
VMEMBER NAME  CMPJFCB                                                            
V//NGJFCB   JOB (P,KBTB,BB2994),'MVSNBY-CMP',CLASS=A,                    JOB40337
V//           REGION=0M,MSGCLASS=W,NOTIFY=&SYSUID    
v// CYX sss eee

Group Number: 1
VMEMBER NAME  CMPJFCB                                                            
V//NGJFCB   JOB (P,KBTB,BB2994),'MVSNBY-CMP',CLASS=A,                    JOB40337
V//           REGION=0M,MSGCLASS=W,NOTIFY=&SYSUID    
v
v//

Group Number: 2
VMEMBER NAME  CMPJFCB                                                            
V//NGJFCB   JOB (P,KBTB,BB2994),'MVSNBY-CMP',CLASS=A,                    JOB40337
V//           REGION=0M,MSGCLASS=W,NOTIFY=&SYSUID    
v
v//
v/*
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you think it looks more complex ?

Comment: Mine is indeed more complex than yours. I'm glad you found your own solution either way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take and it is working fine for me ...

```
open (FILE, "abc.txt" ) || die "can't open file!";

my $reset=0;
my $SD=1;
while (<FILE>) {

if ( m/VMEMBER NAME/){
   if($reset != 0)
   {
    close OUT;
    }
    open(OUT, ">JOBS_$SD.txt") || die ("File could not found! $i");

    $SD++;
    $reset=1;
   }

print OUT $_;   

}
```